# Refer another Java version in a systemd service file

Tags: bash, systemd, rhel, environment-variables, java

I have an application which requires JAVA_HOME environment to be set for a successfull running. On the RHEL server, however the current version of java points to "**openjdk version "1.8.0_302**".

Below is the service file I have configured so that it can execute only through a specific user and also defined JAVA_HOME path.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=testuser
Restart=always
RestartSec=5sec
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
Environment="OPENICF_OPTS=-Xmx1024m"
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/path to jdk/JDK/jdk-11.0.15.1/
ExecStart=/path to conf file/bin/Connect.sh /start
```

On enabling and starting this service, this is still executing the shell script using openjdk 1.8 version which is not compatible with the application. Hence, the service fails to start and become active.

For the reference, below is a brief snippet of my shell script **Connect.sh**. In the bash  script, you can see how the java variable is defined.

```
# Check Java availability
if type -p 'java' >/dev/null; then
    JAVA=java
elif [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ];  then
    JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
else
    echo JAVA_HOME not available, Java is needed to run the Server
    echo Please install Java and set the JAVA_HOME accordingly
    exit 1
fi
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue? I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

at the beginning of `Connect.sh`, or, *assuming you use `"$JAVA"` instead of `java` all over your script*, remove:

```
if type -p java >/dev/null; then
    JAVA=java
el
```

or make it the second case, at least:

```
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ];  then
    JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
elif type -p java >/dev/null; then
    JAVA=java
...
```

or:

```
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ];  then
    JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
else
    JAVA=java
fi


if ! type -p "$JAVA" >/dev/null; then
    echo Cannot find java as instructed
    exit 1
fi
```

(Certainly this approach means it should ignore e.g. `/usr/bin/java` as long as there's a `JAVA_HOME` env var set, regardless of whether the path in the env var actually exists or so.)

Comment: How can we do this through service?

Comment: The `PATH` env var, although I don't think there's a way to concat the path you want to add to it with the currently one imported/set in systemd (but it might not even be necessary if `java` is the only program your script runs). You can at best hard code it (e.g. `Environment=PATH=/path to jdk/JDK/jdk-11.0.15.1/bin:/usr/bin`), AFAIK.